# What is wrong with this proof that $\pi=\infty$

Tags: infinity, pi

Does this "proof" show that $\pi =\infty$???

http://www.academia.edu/1611664/Sum_of_an_Infinite_sequence_PAPER

Is there something wrong with the subbing in of infinity at the end of the paper?

Comment: So is the author of this paper claiming that a circle's circumference is infinitely larger than its diameter? I'm guessing he/she got confused by calculations and forgot the basic definition of $\pi$

Comment: If the proper limit is taken at the end, the result should be $\pi$ radians is equal to $180$ degrees, which is just a simple unit conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are precisely right. The paper replaces taking the limit of an expression as $k\to \infty$ with simply plugging in the "value" $k=\infty$, which is absurd. The author then concludes that
$$\pi=\infty\sin(\pi/\infty)\cdot\frac12=\infty$$
and even if the first equality where valid and the rules of extended arithmetic used to evaluate $\infty\sin(\pi/\infty)\cdot \frac12$, we get
$$\infty\sin(\pi/\infty)\cdot \frac12=\infty\sin(0)\cdot\frac12=\infty\cdot 0$$
which is an indeterminate form.

Comment: @Ethan: Look at the information at the top of the paper: "School: Anglican Church Grammar School". It's not a publication, it's a school paper.

Comment: @GlenO lol sorry, I am clueless with this sort of thing

Comment: It appears that anyone can just upload whatever they want...and the .edu suffix is misleading, it's not affiliated with any university

Answer (score 1):

That proof is **wrong** from the start.

- First off, when working with Calculus (i.e differentiation, and integration), we always use *radians* instead of *degrees*, i.e, the line: $\sin \left( \frac{180}{k} \right) = \frac{180}{k} - \frac{ \left( \frac{180}{k} \right) ^ 3}{3} + ...$ is plain wrong!!! This is because one of the fundamental/basic limits $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ **only** holds when *x* is measured in radian.
- Secondly, when evaluating limits, one cannot just plug $\infty$ in like that, this is what others have pointed out.

Comment: Your first point is incorrect. One typically works with radians, but one could work with degrees just as well (although the author's notation is bad; they should include a degree symbol). And $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ in degrees as well.

Comment: @Alex Becker: Really? Have you tried plugging in some number near 0, and set your calculator in degree mode to see if $\frac{\sin(0.0001 ^\circ)}{0.0001}$ is near 1? The proof of $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ does require $x$ to be measured in radians. And moreover $\sin (0.0001^\circ)$ is nowhere to be "near" 0.0001, but $\sin(0.0001 \mbox{rad}) \approx 0.0001$.

Comment: You have to make various reinterpretations (i.e. the denominator is in degrees as well), which are non-standard but perfectly consistent. I agree it is troublesome and not worthwhile though.